# Linux terminal not working in VMware

Tags: linux

Unfortunately I deleted some files when I login,I restarted my system and second open VMware and open my virtual machine after booting In login page is stuck,mouse not working to login

Comment: What's your question? How do you think we can help? Is this even a programming issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as required for Stackoverflow. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. The help also has a list of other SE sites that you can look thru to find one appropriate for your question.

Comment: What files you deleted? the login page is stalled, that means how can you enter into the terminal if the login is stalled?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

what files did you delete?
you can enter the text mode by pressing `ctrl+alt+f2` and check your file system

Comment: deleted from this : in linux terminal -> computer -> file system
some tmp files deleted and cache files deleted, may be this files in trash ,if i able to open this i will get it back
pls help

Comment: do you mean you delete these files from `/tmp` directory

Comment: if you are a root user you'll find your files here `/root/.local/share/Trash/files`

Comment: My main problem is login ,I put the picture above, login page stuck and mouse pointer is also stuck

Comment: if you can't  enter the text mode by pressing `ctrl+alt+f2` then login single user mode from the `grub boot menu` then you will be able to user terminal window

Comment: How to get grub boot menu ,pls instruct the steps

Comment: [grub boot menu](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/images/grub2.png)
this is a picture of the grub boot menu

Comment: But my system rhel (Linux) in VMware,it's not showing like that options

Comment: when the system is counting 3 minutes when it is starting
you press Enter one time then that option will appear to you
or you can google it to understand what i'm talking about by pictures